# Django tinymce display issue

Tags: python, django, tinymce

I installed tinymce in my django admin in order to beh able to insert code/videos etc in my questions on my quiz-app. But, when I go to display the questions, it appears in code, like if in my tinymce tool I write "c", in the question displayed it will be as follow in the pic:

[image]

quiz/admins.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Questions
from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE
from django.db import models



# Register your models here.

class QuestionsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = [
    'question',
    'optiona',
    'optionb',

    ]

    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': TinyMCE()},
    }



admin.site.register(Questions, QuestionsAdmin)
```

quiz/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.

class Questions(models.Model):
    CAT_CHOICES = (
    ('datascience', 'DataScience'),
    ('productowner', 'ProductOwner'),
    ('businessanalyst', 'BusinessAnalyst'),
    #('sports','Sports'),
    #('movies','Movies'),
    #('maths','Maths'),
    #('generalknowledge','GeneralKnowledge'),


)
    question = models.TextField(max_length = 850)
    optiona = models.TextField(max_length = 800)
    optionb = models.TextField(max_length = 800)
    optionc = models.TextField(max_length = 800)
    optiond = models.TextField(max_length = 800)
    answer = models.TextField(max_length = 850)
    category = models.TextField(max_length=20, choices = CAT_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-category',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

piattaforma/settings.py

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'height': 360,
    'width': 1120,
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 20,
    'selector': 'textarea',
    'theme': 'modern',
    'plugins': '''
            textcolor save link image media preview codesample contextmenu
            table code lists fullscreen  insertdatetime  nonbreaking
            contextmenu directionality searchreplace wordcount visualblocks
            visualchars code fullscreen autolink lists  charmap print  hr
            anchor pagebreak
            ''',
    'toolbar1': '''
            fullscreen preview bold italic underline | fontselect,
            fontsizeselect  | forecolor backcolor | alignleft alignright |
            aligncenter alignjustify | indent outdent | bullist numlist table |
            | link image media | codesample |
            ''',
    'toolbar2': '''
            visualblocks visualchars |
            charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor |  code |
            ''',
    'contextmenu': 'formats | link image',
    'menubar': True,
    'statusbar': True,
    }
```

piattaforma/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('core.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('quiz/', include('quiz.urls')),
    path('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),


]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most web frameworks escape HTML rendered to the page by default to stop accidentally injecting unexpected code into the page.  You can use Django's safe filter to stop this from happening. In your template you would do something like this:

```
{{ instance.the_html_field|safe }}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#safe